# If $f$ is continuous, real and $f'$ is bounded, is $f$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a real valued function continuous and bounded below by (including) $0$, differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $f′$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$. How to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,∞)$?

Edit: sorry for the typos

Comment: Your question shows lack of effort in writing, making a bad quality post. There's no sense in "continuous on bounded" and somewhere the name of the function changed from f to g

Answer (score 3):

if $f'\le M$, by the mean value theorem, for each $x$ and $y$ there is a $c\in (x,y)$ such as:

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)(x-y)|=|f'(c)|\cdot |(x-y)|\le M |x-y|$$

So $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Use MVT and the bound $M$ of the derivative. Take $\delta=\epsilon/M$.